# .setZoom() function on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I create a map using:

```
var mapOptions = {
        zoom : 15
    };
    //Create map.
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

I add a slider bar on html file :

```
 <div class="sliderBar" id="sliderBar">
                <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" step="1"
                    onchange="showValue(this.value)" /> <span id="range">1</span>
</div>
```

So when the value of the slider bar changed, I evoke `showValue(this.value)` function

With this function I have to changed the map zoom's, but it works only the first time.
So, when I change value works, but if I change the value again doesn't work.

This is my function:

```
function showValue(newValue) {
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = newValue;

    //var value=1;
    value = newValue;  

    if(50<value<=100){
        map.setZoom(11);
    }else if(25<value<=50){
        map.setZoom(12);
    }else if(10<value<=25){
        map.setZoom(13);
    }else if(5<value<=10){
        map.setZoom(14);
    }else{
        map.setZoom(15);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for the same or upload the page to see it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found / solved . Problem with if condition

try the condition in this way

```
function showValue(newValue) {
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = newValue;


    value = newValue;  

    if ( value > 10 &&  value <= 25){
        map.setZoom(13);
        return 
    }
    if ( value > 25 &&  value <= 50){
        map.setZoom(12);
        return; 
    }
    if ( value > 50 && value <= 100){
        map.setZoom(11);
        return
    }
    if (  value > 5 && value <= 10){
        map.setZoom(14);
        return
    }

    map.setZoom(15);
    return 
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't specified... Map is declare outside the function